# Find the boundary and interior of $C= A \cup B$?

Tags: general-topology

> Given that $A=\{(x,y)\mid y=0\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\mid x>0\text{ and }y\neq0\}$, find the boundary and interior of the following subsets of $\mathbb R^2$
>   $$
> C=  A \cup B
> $$

I was  trying to visualize the diagram,   here the some of my ideas

[image]

From the diagram I can conclude that the boundary of $C$ will be  $R^2$ and the interior is also $R^2$.

Is my thinking correct or not? Please verify it and tell me the solutions.

Comment: The first set $A$ is the $X$-axis. The second $B$ is the open right-hand semi-plane minus the positive part of the $X$-axis. The interior of their union is going to be the open righ-hand semi-plane. The boundary will be the union of the $X$ and $Y$ axes, minus the positive part of the $X$-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong. The interior of $A\cup B$ is $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,x>0\}$ and the boundary of $A\cup B$ is$$\{(x,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,x<0\}\cup\{(0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,y\in\mathbb{R}\}.\tag1$$

Indeed, if $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $x>0$, then $D\bigl((x,y),x)\bigr)$ is contained in $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,x>0\}$, which is a subset of $A\cup B$. Therefore, $(x,y)$ belongs to the interior of $A\cup B$. And if $x\leqslant 0$, there are, for each $r>0$ points in $D\bigl((x,y),x)\bigr)$ with $x<0$ and $y>0$. Therefore, $(x,y)$ is not in the interior of $A\cup B$.

On the other hand, $\overline{A\cup B}=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\middle|\,x\geqslant0\right\}\cup\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in(-\infty,0)\}$. Since the boundary of $A\cup B$ is its closure minus its interior, the boundary is $(1)$.

Comment: im not getting  @ jose carlos sir      can u elaborate in more detail  ?

Comment: @lomber It's done.

Comment: thanks a lots @jose carlos santos sir

Answer (score 1):

The union $C$ is also the (disjoint) union of the half-plane $H$ where $x>0$ together with the the set $K$ consisting of the points $(x,0)$ with $x\le0$.

Clearly $H$ is an open subset of $C$ and no point in $K$ has a neighborhood contained in $C$. Therefore the interior of $C$ is $H$.

Can you prove that the boundary is the union of $K$ and the $y$-axis? Hint: what's the closure of $H$?

Comment: thanks for giving hints @egreg